# How to `git checkout <commit-ID> <filename>` with VScode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-checkout

From the command line, if I want to go back to a previous version of a specific file, I can checkout this file with a commit-ID like this :

`git checkout <commit-ID> <filename>`

I wonder how can I achieve the same thing with VScode ?

The source control menu in VScode is quiet weak and does not do much, I probably need an extension to do more sophisticated stuff. I saw edamagit that is inspired from magit on Emacs which is quiet powerful, but don't know how to use magit for doing this.

Comment: why create GUI for actions that almost nobody uses frequently, just type the command in the terminal